# Multiple files argument to main function

Tags: java, file, file-io, program-entry-point, args

I want to  process  multiple text files ( eg. compare 2 files) and pass the files as argument to the main function. How do I do that ? How to I pass multiple files arguments from the command line?

```
import java.io.File;
class MultiFileApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Read file 1
        // Read file 2
        //Process File 1 & 2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
java YourApp file1.txt file2.txt
```

Those strings can then be accessed in `main` as `args[0]` & `args[1]`.

Comment: Yep, or have it load some sort of set-up file that holds the file names. 1+

Comment: @Andrew is there any limit to no of argument in the command line?

Comment: I think so.  It basically comes down to how long a line can be entered in the command line of that OS.  If the user needs to type that many file names though, it is going to be a mess.  Perhaps use @HovercraftFullOfEels advice re. one name of a file that itself contains the list.  Alternately, look at specifying the file names in a more generic form.  E.G. `file .txt` might be taken as 'the file must start with `file` and end with `.txt`'.  You could then create a file filter in code that matches those conditions.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass file names(or rather absolute file path) to java as command line arguments as

```
java MainFile file1.txt file2.txt
```

Inside your Java code you can read these files using the following code

```
public class SomeClass() {
URL url = getClass().getResource(args[0]);
File myFile = new File(url.getPath());
InputStream input = new FileInputStream(myFile);
// ...
}
```

or

```
public class SomeClass() {
InputStream input = getClass().getResourceAsStream(args[0]);
// ...
}
```